# Ubuntu 13.10 Can't shutdown

Tags: 13.10, shutdown, lenovo, reboot

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my Lenovo Thinkpad S431, but it can't shutdown. Any kind of shutdown only restarts the laptop. I've tried all sorts of things from re-installing Ubuntu to shutting down from the terminal. I've read many discussions about this issue, but I can't find a solution. Any advice would be great. Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you shutdown from terminal with a command like `sudo shutdown -h now`? Please add any command output.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to try and shut it down without any devices plugged in the usb ports.
I [have read](http://ftbeowulf.wordpress.com/2014/01/01/ubuntu-13-10-reboots-instead-of-shutting-down/) that some devices may cause your PC/laptop to start up after a shutdown.

If that doesn't work you may want to try [what this Ubuntu Forums post suggests](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188726&p=12852203#post12852203).

Comment: Please provide *a rough summary* of what the post you're linking to contains - give us the important bits instead of just linking to them! :)